# How can I list duplicate rows in a table with the same two columns?

Tags: sql-server

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] (
    [PhraseId]              UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [English]               NVARCHAR (250)   NOT NULL,
    [Kanji]                 NVARCHAR (250)   NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC) );
```

What I would like to do is to get a list of all the duplicate rows (with English and Kanji) columns used to detect a duplicate.

In other words if there are rows like this:

```
English   Kanji

aa        bb
aa        cc
aa        bb
aa        dd
aa        ee
aa        dd
```

I would like to get a report showing

```
aa        bb
aa        dd
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table)

Comment: This question has been answered many times. You already asked it too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44001073/how-can-i-list-duplicate-values-out-of-a-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
select English,Kanji from Phrase
group by English,Kanji
having count(*)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Row_Number() we can do it

```
;WITH CTE(English,Kanji)
as
(
select 'aa','bb' UNION ALL
select 'aa','cc' UNION ALL
select 'aa','bb' UNION ALL
select 'aa','dd' UNION ALL
select 'aa','ee' UNION ALL
select 'aa','dd' 
)
SELECT English
    ,Kanji
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY English
            ,Kanji ORDER BY English
                ,Kanji
            ) AS Seq
    FROM CTE
    ) dt
WHERE dt.Seq <> 1
```

OutPut

```
English Kanji
-------------
aa      bb
aa      dd
```